# How to sample elements in a list nested within a tibble?

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

```
a = tribble(~i,~k,
            c(1,2,3),2) %>%
  mutate(picks = sample(i,k))
```

I want to sample `k` elements within `i`, but `mutate` thinks that I want to sample `i` as singular element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close; just need to add in `rowwise` and wrap `sample` in `list()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

a = tribble(~i,~k,
            c(1,2,3),2) %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(picks = list(sample(i,k)))

a

#  i             k picks    
#  <list>    <dbl> <list>   
#1 <dbl [3]>     2 <dbl [2]>
```